# how to remove or reduce unused javascripts in React webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, pagespeed, webp

Because of performance issues, I need to remove or reduce unused codes in build time.

This is my unused bytes in coverage tab of developer tools.

[image]

I need a tested, best practice way of solving this problem.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: @Andy I've used it,  but It doesn't work well